# How to set up weekly repeating UILocalNotifications with iOS 8 deprecations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Prior to iOS 8, scheduling weekly repeating notifications was easy, we just assigned `NSWeekCalendarUnit` to the `notification.repeatInterval` value.  Now with iOS 8, pretty much all the `NSCalendarUnit` values have been deprecated and replaced, mostly so Apple could rename them from `NSDayCalendarUnit` to `NSCalendarUnitDay` for consistency.  However, they changed `NSWeekCalendarUnit` into `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` and `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`, with no clear explanation of what the difference is, and the `UILocalNotification` documentation still talks in terms of the deprecated values.

I want a `UILocalNotification` to ***repeat every 7 days***.  I assumed `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` was the correct value, but when I use it, I get no repetition.  Testing is time consuming, because each test takes a week!

Does anyone know which of the new week calendar units should be used for a weekly repeating local notification, or should the deprecated values continue to be used despite the warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming **Gregorian Calendar**, it seems `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear` is value either from  `1 - 53` or `0 - 52` which represents number of week *within the calendar year*. `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` is `1 - 5` or `0 - 4` which represents week within the month (Undocumented stuff, these are personal opinions ). 
In my experience i found NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear working.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I figured out that a way to quickly test these is to create a repeating notification to fire soon, then check its next fire date after it has fired once (which is displayed with a po notification).  Both NSWeekCalendarUnit and NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear work for creating notifications that repeat every 7 days, so NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear is the best to use because it is not deprecated.