# Repeat a UILocalNotification each week at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

If I schedule a notification on Monday January 4 at 1:00pm, I'd like it to be able to repeat each week on Monday. According to this blog post http://useyourloaf.com/blog/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html I thought that `NSWeekCalendarUnit` would work well, however it's deprecated for iOS 8+. The documentation says the replacement for it is either `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth` or `NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear`. If I'm understanding this correctly, the former would have the notification repeat on the first week of each month, and then latter would repeat every year on the first week of the month? Or am I misunderstanding something?

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit; // Deprecated
```

Comment: Why not find out when Monday is, then set the repatInterval to 604800 (seconds in a week)

Comment: This post answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754384/how-to-set-up-weekly-repeating-uilocalnotifications-with-ios-8-deprecations

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog No, don't assume every week has a fixed number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< dateArray.count; i++) {

    UILocalNotification *nextNotif = [yourOriginalNotifMonday mutableCopy];
    nextNotif.fireDate = [mondayDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:i*ONE_WEEK];

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:nextNotif];
}
```

And to test your code:

```
NSDate *mondayDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5.0];
const int ONE_WEEK = 2;//2 seconds instead of 7*ONE_DAY;
```

and immediately put your app in background.